# how to manage users and roles using koa koa-passport with rethinkdb

Tags: koa, koa-passport

I am new to koa. i want to implement a simple admin panel with users and roles. is there any package available for managing roles with koa and rethink db. i am using koa-passport for basic authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided much info, but I'll try to help you get started.

Passport is just for authentication aka login/logout.

Sounds like you want an authorization system (a system that determines what a user is allowed to do, like if they are allowed to view the admin panel). This system doesn't need to touch your authentication system.

The simplest solution is to add a `role` field to your users table that's always set to `"ADMIN"`, `"MEMBER"` (default), or `"BANNED"`.

Using Passport, if a user is logged in, attach them to the request:

```
if (user) {
  req.user = user;
}
```

Now in your routes you can just check `user.role` to implement your authorization check:

```
app.get('/admin', function(req, res) {
  // Send a 403 Forbidden error if the user is not an ADMIN
  if (!req.user || req.user.role !== 'ADMIN') {
    return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
  }
  res.render('admin.html', { data: ... });
});
```

That's the basis of a role-based authorization system, though very basic.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable information.

Yes i want authorization system. we can add role in user table but if we want to give more roles to a specific user then this might be not handled in this scenario.  Actually i am a asp.net developer and want something like asp.net identity.